# How to get the value of a child element in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to edit a existing XML file through C# and need to identify the sections I want (block name="treeDeadTree01" and block name="treeDeadTree02") Then get the value of "count" in the child element "drop". I have been able to identify the elements (block name="treeDeadTree01" and block name="treeDeadTree02") but cant figure out how to get the value of "count" from the element "drop" of the specific elements (block name="treeDeadTree01" and block name="treeDeadTree02")

The XML file is a config file from the game 7 Days To Die and I am trying to make a application to more easily edit the configs of the game. After I find the value of "count" I am putting it into a DataGridView.

My question is, how after I find the block element I want do I find the value of "count" in the "drop" child element of the block element?

This is a section of the XML file I am trying to edit

```
<blocks>
<block name="treeDeadTree01">
    <property name="Extends" value="treeMaster" />
    <property name="Model" value="Entities/Trees/White_Oak22Prefab" />
    <property name="ModelOffset" value="0,-0.3,0" />
    <property name="MultiBlockDim" value="1,4,1" />
    <property name="BigDecorationRadius" value="4" />
    <property name="Collide" value="movement,melee,bullet,arrow,rocket" />
    <drop event="Harvest" name="resourceWood" count="515" tag="oreWoodHarvest" />
    <property name="ParticleOnDeath" value="treeGib_dead_01" />
    <!-- <drop event="Destroy" name="treePlantedMaple1m" count="x"/> -->
    <property name="SortOrder2" value="0140" />
    <!-- SortTree -->
 </block>
<block name="treeDeadTree02">
    <!-- almost a shrub -->
    <property name="Extends" value="treeMaster" />
    <property name="IsTerrainDecoration" value="true" />
    <property name="Model" value="Entities/Trees/Haunted_Shrub_WastelandPrefab" />
    <property name="ModelOffset" value="0,-0.3,0" />
    <property name="Collide" value="melee,rocket" />
    <!-- no movement effect on Shape="ModelTree" -->
    <drop event="Harvest" name="resourceWood" count="215" tag="oreWoodHarvest" />
    <property name="ParticleOnDeath" value="treeGib_dead_02" />
    <!-- <drop event="Destroy" name="treePlantedMaple1m" count="x"/> -->
    <property name="FilterTags" value="foutdoor,ftrees,fshrubbery" />
    <property name="SortOrder1" value="a060" />
  </block>
</blocks
```

My current code

```
 string[] GatherRateNames = {"treeDeadTree01", "treeDeadTree02"};

 string XMLBlocksPath = "F:\\SteamLibrary\\steamapps\\common\\7 Days To Die\\Data\\Config\\blocks.xml";

private void makeGatherRatesList()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(XMLBlocksPath);
            XmlNodeList aNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/blocks/block");
            foreach (XmlNode aNode in aNodes)
            {
                XmlAttribute idAttribute = aNode.Attributes["name"];
                if (GatherRateNames.Contains(idAttribute.ToString()))
                {
                addItemToList(idAttribute.ToString(),"Value of count");
                }
            }
        }
        private void addItemToList(string itemName, int itemValue)
        {

        }
```

In the end I want to get the name of the block like "treeDeadTree01" then get the value of "count" inside the element "drop" of that block and put both of those in a DataGridView and be able to edit the value of count through the DataGridView then repeat that with every block I need.

Comment: Okay, we know what you want. Now, **what's your question**? Please fix your post so that it includes a [mcve], showing what you've tried so far, an explanation of what that does, what you want instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "block")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("block");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    Block newBlock = new Block();
                    blocks.Add(newBlock);

                    XElement xBlock = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    newBlock.name = (string)xBlock.Attribute("name");
                    XElement drop = xBlock.Element("drop");
                    if (drop != null)
                    {
                        object count = drop.Attribute("count");
                        newBlock.count = (count == null)? null : (decimal?)decimal.Parse((string)count, culture);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public class Block
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public decimal? count { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried using this everything returned as null.

Comment: Either you are reading a different xml file or there are namespaces in the xml that aren't shown.  I made a change that may work to add a default namespace.

Comment: I got this working perfectly when trying it on a XML file with just the XML code I shared above but I cannot get it working on the actual file. The actual file is 1.3 MB so I wasn't able to upload it to pastebin. From the error I get it looks like it might be because not every <block> has the "drop" element.

Error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) returned null.

Comment: For huge xml files you need to use XmlReader.  I update my code to include a XmlReader solution.  If the issue is with the actual xml new code will help isolate the row of data where issue is occurring.

Comment: When using the new XmlReader code I get a error on this line "newBlock.count = (int)xBlock.Element("drop").Attribute("count");" it is returning null.

Comment: On first row(s) or in the middle?  Changing type from int to int? will solve issue if it is in middle of file.  Are any blocks missing the drop element?

Comment: There are some blocks that are missing the drop element. And I'm not sure what you are asking in your first question.

Comment: I'm getting an error 'Input string was not in a correct format.' on this line  newBlock.count = (int?)drop.Attribute("count");

Comment: What is the value of the attribute count when the error occurs.

Comment: The value is "3,8". It looks like in a few places in the XML file there are multiple numbers as the value of count.

Comment: Change int to decimal 2 places.  In the class and in the while loop.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with the same value of count. This is what the 2 lines I believe you wanted me to change look like: 
    newBlock.count = (decimal?)drop.Attribute("count");
    public decimal? count { get; set; }
Is that what I was supposed to do?

Comment: Exactly.  What is the trace stack exception?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what your looking for but this is the stack trace of the exception I hope that's what you are asking for:    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute.op_Explicit(XAttribute attribute)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\joshu\source\repos\XML Test\XML Test\Program.cs:line 34

Comment: I didn't notice the decimal point was a comma (not a period).   So I updated code to accept a comma as a decimal point.